How to deal with required fields when the user may not have all the data or may not want to fill it all out?
I have a question about how to approach this situation:
Inside platform there is a configuration page for integration with other apps.
There are 2 integrations that are always required and user MUST fill them to have the platform running. Other integrations are optional.
We considered the option of having the page empty on first entry, and having the user add integrations themselves using the Add button at the top of the page. Or displaying all integrations at once, with the option to Save at the top.
Header action - Add or Save?
So basically Add button with empty page cannot be done as section 1 and 2 has to be visible at all times, BUT we also want users to be able to save entering just section 1 and not fill in all the details of section 3, so all sections cannot be at once from the start with the Save button on top.

Each section represents an integration with a given app.
Section 1 and 2 are required and must always be visible. All fields to fill in are required.
Section 3 is optional, but if already added, its content is also required.
How to present this? What should be the global action on page? Do you have any ideas?

Please add a clear image to the post instead of a link.

Agreed, this needs a good image and some clearer explanation of the issue. How does Section 3 get added? Is it in the user's control? Can it be removed if it has been added in error and is optional? Is the issue here that section 3 is causing them problems, or that they may not have the required info for the OTHER two sections as well? The clearer you can be with the flow and the issues the easier it will be to help.

Not fully clear on the use case of section 3 and the target audience. So let me help by giving the most common way this is done in similar situations in various B2B products:

+Add section button
Remove section button - and this removes the mandatory fields too.


